# Design pattern: store globals in a single class

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I want to store many "globals" into a single class. Is there any design pattern I can follow?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's called [Big Ball of Mud](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_ball_of_mud).

Comment: There are times when you have no different choice.

Comment: @Lotus: I'm not saying don't do it. Just call it what it is.

Comment: Nathan, I'm waiting for your design of the simple memo game, I'm sure you can teach me a lot.

Comment: @Lotus: You say, "There are times when you have no different choice." Maybe, but you have to believe there's a better way, or else you will not look very hard. read the quote at http://raganwald.posterous.com/yoda-lectures-rim-management.

Answer (score 2):

Typically this is what the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) is used for.

The singleton is probably both the most popular, and [most reviled pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx).

Comment: My situation is a little different than Singleton's. I need a sort of repository for another class to use.

Comment: @Lotus - It isn't very clear to me what you're needing that can't properly be done with a classic singleton. It could be that going into a bit more detail in your question may get you better answers. It could also be that I'm just being dense. It happens.

Comment: I beg your pardon. I've a little tile-based game (a simple memo game). Every tile is of Tile class. When you click a tile you can change the value of one of its members, but in my case I need to store elsewhere the name and other properties of the tile I clicked because when I click the second one I must confront a value contained inside it with the previous one.

Comment: Okay...why does any of that need to be global?

Comment: The second instance of Tile must read which tile was previously clicked as I don't store this value in the first tile (it would be unreacheable...)...

Comment: By the way, I created another class full of get/set static methods and I call them when needed from Tile instances.

Comment: The game is very similar to this one (the cards here are my tiles, even if I have many more): http://www.didigames.us/Mermaid_Melody.html

Comment: Please, who added 1 to TED's comment, could tell me how he would do?

Comment: As far as I see it, you don't need many globals, you need one variable scoped at the game level, of type Tile, with a name like "LastClicked" or something like that.

Comment: Not exactly: I need a "clicked" boolean (because it could be the first or the second click), I need to push the name of the previous and current tile into an array (to perform conditional operations, cover/uncover etc.), I need to store (decreasing it) the number of successful tries (and perform actions when the number is 0) and a couple of things I don't remember. Why you say there should be a variable of Tile type at the game level? The tile is only a piece of the game and is created/designed/instaciated by the main at startup.

Comment: @Lotus - You should add some of this discussion to the question (or make another question), and let us try to help you solve the real problem.

Comment: Don, I wasn't doing homework, so I've no real problem: the game as I built it perfectly works. I was looking for tips about better architecture. My main creates the tiles and positions them. Every tile is clickable and the click is managed by the tile itself. Since tile must match to make them disappear, I need to store in a centralized location some values, one of them representing the previously clicked tile name: when the user clicks the second tile, in the class tile itself there's a verify method and to make it work, the tile must look for a value to perform a comparison.

Comment: Since, that value CAN'T live in a member of the Tile class, it should be stored outside it. In the very first version of the game, I put it in the main: since I did non like the fact that the main was used for initizialization purposes AND for "business" I added a TileHelper class to manage all the things that regular instances of Tile can't manage.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for a service locator, or dependency injection.

Martin Fowler on both: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is pretty much the [Multiton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern), which is closely related to the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

It manages a map of named instances as key-value pairs.

It has the same drawbacks as a singleton, and should be avoided unless you really need it.  And you probably don't really need it.

Comment: I did something similar to the Multiton in the TileHelper class. I understand anybody is criticizing the Singleton/Multiton, but I don't understand which would be a better way to accomplish the task in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

If the "globals" are of the same type/interface I would suggest to consider [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).